# Add growth columns to this table in sqlite

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have this table `Sales` in sqlite3 database.

```
Name    Sales       Date
"Vent"  "75.998"    "2014-12-31"
"Vent"  "153.988"   "2015-12-31"
"Vent"  "180.678"   "2016-12-31"
"Vent"  "372.819"   "2017-12-31"
"DBG"   "4046.0"    "2014-12-31"
"DBG"   "4454.0"    "2015-12-31"
"DBG"   "4238.0"    "2016-12-31"
"DBG"   "4371.0"    "2017-12-31"
```

I would like to add extra columns to this table to show sales growth. The new table will look something like this;

```
Name    Sales       Date          Year1_Growth      Year2_Growth        Year3_Growth
"Vent"  "75.998"    "2014-12-31"  null              null                null 
"Vent"  "153.988"   "2015-12-31"  153.988/75.998    null                null
"Vent"  "180.678"   "2016-12-31"  180.678/153.988   180.678/75.998      null
"Vent"  "372.819"   "2017-12-31"  372.819/180.678   372.819/153.988     372.819/75.998
"DBG"   "4046.0"    "2014-12-31"  null              null                null 
"DBG"   "4454.0"    "2015-12-31"  4454/4046         null                null 
"DBG"   "4238.0"    "2016-12-31"  4238/4454         4238/4046           null 
"DBG"   "4371.0"    "2017-12-31"  4371/4238         4371/4454           4371/4046
```

Any hints on how to get started on the sql code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can achieve this via a series of self joins.  Note that in the query below I actually print out the text ratios of the sales figures.  This should help you confirm that the logic in the query is correct.  If you want actual numerical ratios, then just use e.g. `s1.Sales / s2.Sales` instead of the string concatenation.

```
SELECT
    s1.Name,
    s1.Sales,
    s1.Date,
    s1.Sales || '/' || s2.Sales AS first,      -- use s1.Sales / s2.Sales
    s1.Sales || '/' || s3.Sales AS second,     -- for actual ratio
    s1.Sales || '/' || s4.Sales AS third
FROM Sales s1
LEFT JOIN Sales s2
    ON s1.Name = s2.Name AND
       CAST(SUBSTR(s1.Date, 1, 4) AS int) = CAST(SUBSTR(s2.Date, 1, 4) AS int) + 1
LEFT JOIN Sales s3
    ON s1.Name = s3.Name AND
       CAST(SUBSTR(s1.Date, 1, 4) AS int) = CAST(SUBSTR(s3.Date, 1, 4) AS int) + 2
LEFT JOIN Sales s4
    ON s1.Name = s4.Name AND
       CAST(SUBSTR(s1.Date, 1, 4) AS int) = CAST(SUBSTR(s4.Date, 1, 4) AS int) + 3
ORDER BY
    s1.Name, s1.Date;
```

[image]

### Demo

Comment: Thanks. I don't need the divisor to appear in the column. The divisor in the question details is for illustration on how to compute the sales growth. 
I would like the end result of the division to appear.

Comment: @user3848207 Then just take the ratio `s1.Sales / s2.Sales`.  It wasn't clear from your question what you actually wanted.

Comment: Sorry for lack of clarity. Thanks for the answer. I've marked it as the right answer.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using Sqlite 3.25 or newer, the joins can be eliminated and this can be done very easily using window functions:

```
SELECT name
     , sales
     , date
     , sales / lag(sales, 1) OVER past_sales AS Year1_Growth
     , sales / lag(sales, 2) OVER past_sales AS Year2_Growth
     , sales / lag(sales, 3) OVER past_sales AS Year3_Growth
FROM sales
WINDOW past_sales AS (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY date)
ORDER BY name DESC, date;
```

gives

```
name        sales       date        Year1_Growth  Year2_Growth  Year3_Growth
----------  ----------  ----------  ------------  ------------  ------------
Vent        75.998      2014-12-31  null          null          null        
Vent        153.988     2015-12-31  2.0262112160  null          null        
Vent        180.678     2016-12-31  1.1733251941  2.3774046685  null        
Vent        372.819     2017-12-31  2.0634443595  2.4210912538  4.9056422537
DBG         4046.0      2014-12-31  null          null          null        
DBG         4454.0      2015-12-31  1.1008403361  null          null        
DBG         4238.0      2016-12-31  0.9515042658  1.0474542758  null        
DBG         4371.0      2017-12-31  1.0313827277  0.9813650651  1.0803262481
```

Edit: Dump of sample table schema and data:

```
CREATE TABLE sales(name TEXT, sales REAL, date TEXT);
INSERT INTO sales VALUES('Vent',75.99800000000000466,'2014-12-31');
INSERT INTO sales VALUES('Vent',153.98799999999999954,'2015-12-31');
INSERT INTO sales VALUES('Vent',180.67799999999999727,'2016-12-31');
INSERT INTO sales VALUES('Vent',372.81900000000001683,'2017-12-31');
INSERT INTO sales VALUES('DBG',4046.0,'2014-12-31');
INSERT INTO sales VALUES('DBG',4453.9999999999999999,'2015-12-31');
INSERT INTO sales VALUES('DBG',4238.0000000000000001,'2016-12-31');
INSERT INTO sales VALUES('DBG',4370.9999999999999999,'2017-12-31');
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer using Windows. However, I tried it and got the error. `near "past_sales": syntax error: SELECT name
     , sales
     , date
     , sales / lag(sales, 1) OVER past_sales`

Comment: I wonder if it is caused by window functions not being supported. However, I have created a new database using sqlite3 tool v3.25.

Comment: I literally copy&pasted from a 3.25.2 sqlite3 shell. The query won't work with pre 3.25 versions of the library; if you're using an older one you have to use one of the other answers.

Comment: I ran the query using `DB Browser`. I guess this tool does not support 3.25. Hence, the error appeared. Thanks for your answer using windows. This is something new.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `join`s:

```
select s.*,
       s.sales / nullif(s_1.sales, 0) as year1_growth,
       s.sales / nullif(s_2.sales, 0) as year2_growth,
       s.sales / nullif(s_3.sales, 0) as year3_growth
from sales s left join
     sales s_1
     on s.name = s_1.name and
        strftime('%Y', s.date) = stftime('%Y', s_1.date) + 1 left join
     sales s_2
     on s.name = s_2.name and
        strftime('%Y', s.date) = stftime('%Y', s_2.date) + 2 left join
     sales s_3
     on s.name = s_3.name and
        strftime('%Y', s.date) = stftime('%Y', s_3.date) + 3;
```

Comment: Hmm. Did you try running that? I don't think those `strftime()` comparisons will work as they are even after fixing the typos (`strftime('%Y', s.date)` returns a string, while `strftime('%Y', s_1.date) + 1` evaluates to a number, and comparing a string against a number for equality always fails.)